# Capturing a Cropped Region Successfully, but Struggling with Stereo Audio in Video

Tags: javascript, audio, video, codec, mediarecorder

I'm using [this tutorial](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/web-platform/region-capture/) to record a region of a web page. It is mostly working, but it mixes down the audio that is playing on the browser from 2 to 1 channel. The `container` div referenced below contains a video that has stereo audio. I have some graphic overlays on it, and I want all of it to be saved as a new video. In a future version, I might also have some audio effects going on. All of this should be preserved in the output file, including the stereo panning.

This is the code for when the user starts the screen share:

```
stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({
  video: true,
  audio: { channelCount: 2 },
  preferCurrentTab: true,
})

cropTarget = await CropTarget.fromElement(document.getElementById('container'))
const [track] = stream.getVideoTracks()
await track.cropTo(cropTarget)
recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, {
  mimeType: 'video/webm;codecs=h264,vp9,opus',
})
```

The next step is called when they click on the record button:

```
const suggestedName = Date.now() + `.webm`,
handle = await window.showSaveFilePicker({ suggestedName }),
writable = await handle.createWritable()

recorder.start()
recorder.addEventListener(`start`, async () => {
  video.play()
})
recorder.addEventListener(`dataavailable`, async (event) => {
  await writable.write(event.data)
  if (recorder.state === `inactive`) {
    await writable.close()
  }
})
```

And, finally, when they click on stop:

```
if (recorder && recorder.state !== `inactive`) {
  recorder.stop()
}
```

The `video/webm;codecs=h264,vp9,opus` codec is just the last thing I tried, but I did test without defining any codec. I'm on Chrome 114 on macOS 13.2.

I've been experimenting with different codec options, but outside of this, I'm totally lost since there are no error messages or anything that indicates that something wrong is going on --- outside of the mono video!